# Julia PyPlot can't create quadratic function

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I'm trying to learn to plot things with Julia using PyPlot, and I tried to plot a quadratic function. It does not like how I'm squaring x. I tried using x**2 and x*x, and the compiler did not accept those either. What should I be using to square x?
Thanks

Code @ line 7:

```
x1 = linspace(0,4*pi, 500); y1 = x^2
```

Error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: `*` has no method matching *(::LinSpace{Float64},      
::LinSpace{Float64})
Closest candidates are:
*(::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any...)
*{T}(!Matched::Bidiagonal{T}, ::AbstractArray{T,1})
*(!Matched::Number, ::AbstractArray{T,N})
...
in power_by_squaring at intfuncs.jl:80
in ^ at intfuncs.jl:108
in include_string at loading.jl:282
in include_string at C:\Users\User\.julia\v0.4\CodeTools\src\eval.jl:32
in anonymous at C:\Users\User\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:84
in withpath at C:\Users\User\.julia\v0.4\Requires\src\require.jl:37
in withpath at C:\Users\User\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:53
[inlined code] from C:\Users\User\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:83
in anonymous at task.jl:58
while loading C:\Users\User\Desktop\Comp Sci\Class\plotTest, in expression     
starting on line 7
```

Comment: Note that using `x**2` ought to tell you the correct syntax: `ERROR: syntax: use "^" instead of "**"`. Did that not occur when you tried this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To square every element of an array, use `x.^2`.

Comment: Did not even think about x being an array. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to square all of the elements of an array. This means you need to use the **element-wise** version `x.^2`.